# UITableView crashes on scrolling (Country-List) on github

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

This is a code that i got from github and crashes on the lines i commented, i know EXC BAD ACCESS is when you dont retain or release something but i have ARC enabled so i dont know what to do.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CountryCell *cell = (CountryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CountryCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[_dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:kCountryName]; //here crashes
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[_dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:kCountryCallingCode]; //here crashes

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Does the github file you've download have no ARC support?

Comment: doesn't say anything, this is the one https://github.com/pradyumnad/Country-List/blob/master/README.md

Comment: you mean id ? doesnt matter the tableview is loaded but crashes on scrolling

Comment: is it any problem that i deactivated autolayout? because my project has to be deployed in 4.3 which doesnt have autolayout

Comment: It doesn't have to do anything with Autolayout.. I have downloaded the project and run it. No probs here..

Comment: I tried just now i still get bad access

Comment: @Elgert hi, same here no problem in code ,when scroll fast then some time apps crash for null value exception.but that solve converting string. like..cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:kCountryName]];

Comment: I tried the standalone code and it works for me also. In my project is the problem when i implement it

Comment: any idea how to convert the code to non-ARC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think one of the best way to set text property in label

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:kCountryName]];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[_dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:kCountryCallingCode]];
```

its may be useful ..

Comment: I got the problem, my project is for iOS 4.3 and i cant upgrade it for number of reasons, so do you know how to change the tableview code to non-ARC ?

Comment: the whole project is non-arc and if i convert to arc i get 100+ errors

Comment: if u want change non arc then u manually release object and dealloc them and make shore that in build setting `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` ->No ok fine u just paste code and manually release it. i hope its useful for u . Thanks

Comment: well thats the problem never coded with non-arc projects :/

Comment: if u want to user arc files in your non-arc project then goto build phase and compile source and select your arc file here and set flag to  `-fobjc-arc` .